# Is there a way for SQL queries to handle a database which does not have all the columns requested in the SELECT command?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, winforms

**Introduction**

My Windows Forms Application allows me to load, view and change the settings of a network of industrial controllers on a CAN network. These settings are loaded to a database where all the information is stored. From time to time, clients request new features and the controller firmwares are updated to include new settings. These new settings will need to be loaded to the database hence, I add new columns to the database to be able store them. In addition to this, I am also able to load old databases to view the settings of each controller of an installation.

**Problem Description**

My issue is that each time I add a new column to the database I also have to add another field to the SELECT command of the SQL query. Hence, every time I load an old database to my application the SQL query throws an exception because I am requesting columns which the old database does not have.

**Current Solution**

I have solved this by creating a 'Fill' SQL query for each database type and using the Try-Catch loop where, first I try to query the most amount of columns (latest database type with the most settings), if an exception is thrown I move to the next largest database query. In this way, I will have to create an SQL query for each database size.

**Question**

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I am using Visual Studio and the target .NET framework is 4.0.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: If your application doesn't know which columns are present, then it seems like it will have to use one of the `DbDataAdapter` `FillSchema(...)` methods to get the available columns, which determine the input fields displayed in the user-interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion One**

Keep a common column like "Querykeys" against each database type  which contain comma separated fieldname which can be used in Select Query and then you will first query that field and use the result string to create the query to retrieve data

**Suggestion Two**

If you are changing the Columns or column count of database regularly it means there is a serious problem in your design

Instead try adding the new properties as a child table

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding suggestion 1; unfortunately it would not work with pre-existing customer databases because they do not have a column 'Querykeys'. As for suggestion 2; I am quite new to VB.NET and SQL queries, could explain in more detail what you mean by a child table please?